# Having trouble with AWS4 Signature tutorial, hash doesn't match example

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-api-gateway

I'm working through the tutorial on AWS, trying to calculate the `Authorization` header and I'm stuck.  (Tutorial here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html)

I've narrowed down my problem to a step at the end of task 3.  I can create the signing key as they described and get the same result as they do, 
`c4afb1cc5771d871763a393e44b703571b55cc28424d1a5e86da6ed3c154a4b9`

I can calculate the `stringToSign` as they describe and I get a matching result, 
`AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20150830T123600Z\n20150830/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request\nf536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59`

But when I try to sign the string my result doesn't match their result.

```
var kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create("HMACSHA256");
kha.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("c4afb1cc5771d871763a393e44b703571b55cc28424d1a5e86da6ed3c154a4b9");

var sts = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20150830T123600Z\n20150830/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request\nf536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59";

var signature = HexEncode(kha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sts)));
```

When I run this my signature comes out as
`fe52b221b5173b501c9863cec59554224072ca34c1c827ec5fb8a257f97637b1`

but they say it should be 
`5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924a6f2b5d7`

In task 2 I run my `HexEncode` function as part of creating the HashedCanonicalRequest and that is coming out fine so I don't think it is that function but here it is just in case:

```
private static string HexEncode(byte[] data, bool lowercase = true)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(data[i].ToString(lowercase ? "x2" : "X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I've tried various ways of writing the `sts` like using

```
@"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20150830T123600Z
20150830/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request
f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59"
```

instead of using `\n` but nothing has worked.  I also read through a few of the other postings here on SO but none of those seemed to help either.

Update:
I created this fiddle just to prove to myself that it isn't something environmental but it gets the same answer as my local code.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/A5mVp9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that using

`kha.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("c4afb1cc5771d871763a393e44b703571b55cc28424d1a5e86da6ed3c154a4b9");`

is incorrect.  That string is hex encoded (because that's what it says to do in the tutorial) but you are supposed to use the byte-array version and not hex encode it.  They showed the hex encoded just for display purposes but didn't do a good job of saying to use the regular byte array and DO NOT HEX ENCODE IT! Anyways, that's what solves this.

If you want to see it in action, write a hex decoder:

```
public static byte[] DecodeHex(string hex)
{
    byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
    {
        raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return raw;
}
```

and hex decode the string I listed and use that byte array in the hashing.

```
kha.Key = DecodeHex("c4afb1cc5771d871763a393e44b703571b55cc28424d1a5e86da6ed3c154a4b9");
```